# When a roll is rerolled, how does it interact with other roll-manipulation features (like the Lucky feat)?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, saving-throw

A 14th level Monk has a Diamond Soul.

> Whenever you make a saving throw and fail, you can spend 1 ki point **to reroll it and take the second result**.

A 9th level Fighter has Indomitable.

> You can reroll a saving throw that
>   you fail. If you do so, you **must use the new roll**.

The Lucky feat states that:

> You have 3 luck points. Whenever you make an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw, you can spend one luck point to roll an additional d20. You can choose to spend one of your luck points after you roll the die, but before the outcome is determined.

So, if a Fighter or a Monk re-rolls their Saving Throw, does that mean **they cannot then use Lucky**? Or is the wording just meant to say **you don't pick one of the 2 values**, but instead just the new one?

As an example:

Fighter rolls a WIS Throw, rolls 1 and DM informs him he failed the save. Fighter uses Indomitable and rerolls, getting a 10. Before the DM tells him whether he succeeded or not, can the Fighter decide to roll an additional Luck die, or must he take that 2nd Indomitable roll?

Comment: This may be helpful to you and answerers: [How Lucky Feat Works (Sage Advice)](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/05/21/how-lucky-feat-works/)

Comment: Seems related to: [Can a character use a luck point to affect a roll that was replaced by Portent?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122748/portent-vs-lucky-feat-which-wins)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You can spend Luck on the first roll or the re-roll, or both.

Read the rules carefully. You "spend one of your luck points after you roll the die, but before the outcome is determined". So you use Luck **before you have failed the saving throw**.

Diamond Soul lets you spend a ki point to reroll **whenever you make a saving throw and fail**. That's **after** the outcome is determined. The same goes for Indomitable.

So if you use a Luck point, you get to roll one additional die to determine the outcome of the roll. If you then don't succeed on the saving throw, you've "made a saving throw and failed". So then you can use Diamond Soul or Indomitable to re-roll. If you want, you can use Luck on the re-roll too, before the outcome of that is determined.

Note that if you roll a Lucky die, you can choose to ignore it. It's not a "re-roll" so you don't have to keep it.

Example: Fighter rolls a Wisdom Saving Throw, rolls 1, and decides not to use Luck because they have Indomitable. The DM informs them the save failed. The Fighter uses Indomitable and re-rolls, getting a 10. Before the DM tells them whether they succeeded or not, the Fighter can decide to roll an additional Luck die.

Comment: Actually, if you use a Luck point you end up creating Advantage on the saving throw.  Your last sentence looks correct.

Comment: Luck does not create advantage. It can have an effect mechanically identical to advantage, but it can also be different. Note that Luck does not state that you can "gain advantage on a roll", but that you can "roll an additional d20".

Comment: This would be improved by clarifying that you only re-roll one die if your initial roll was made with advantage or disadvantage. The current phrasing seems to indicate you'd re-roll both.

Comment: @InternetHobo I think it's clear that Luck is not a "re-roll". But the question is about how it interacts with re-rolls, and _those_ are made with advantage or disadvantage if the original roll was.

Comment: @Apocalisp I was referring to the statment "Note that if you had advantage or disadvantage on the first roll, you also have advantage or disadvantage on the re-roll using those features[...]" (those features being Diamond Soul or Indomitable) You only re-roll one of the two dice RAW, but you do indeed still have advantage or disadvantage respectively.

Answer (score 8):

**You should be able to use Lucky to manipulate any roll *as long as the end result is unknown to you.***

...*within the feature's limits.*

> A 9th level Fighter has Indomitable:
>
> You can reroll a saving throw that you fail. If you do so, you must use the **new roll.**

With my emphasis above, a new roll means it's a separate roll from the failed one so the phases of rolling should repeat. That means you should be able to use Lucky since the result of this new roll is undetermined again.

The wording on the *Diamond Soul* is different but I can see the meaning going both ways.

- You must use the second result so you can't manipulate the roll anymore.
- You must use the second result but between rerolling and determining said result you may use Lucky to manipulate it.

  Because Lucky manipulates a roll, not the result, should be the second point.)

Seems a bit based on the DM's understanding of the exact words on these features.

**My understanding:** Whether it is before or after using other features, as long as the end result is unknown, you can choose to spend a Lucky point to roll an additional die and choose which die to use for that roll.

**My opinion:** Using Lucky after using one of those features actually diminishes its power as you could've had the effect of Lucky all along. It's just saving the Lucky point until the last moment of desperation in case you can succeed without it. That sounds to me like actual last second luck which makes it more realistically awesome.  That said I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed.