# Can you use Lucky (feat) followed by Portent to replace a roll that's already been made?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, wizard

### Consider the following scenario:

I am playing a Divination Wizard with the Lucky Feat. He is sufficient level to have access to the Portent feature. He rolls his Divination Dice for the day and rolls very low on both dice.

An enemy attacks me and rolls a Natural 20, a Critical Hit.

My Wizard decides to use Lucky in an attempt to avoid the crit, rolling an additional D20 for the attack and then choosing the lower roll as the result of the attack.

Before the aforementioned roll is made as per the Lucky feat, can my Wizard use the Portent feature to replace the Lucky roll the player is about to make with one of the Divination Dice, thus ensuring a failure?

### Specific Wording

This is the exact wording of the [Lucky](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/lucky) feat (PHB, p. 167):

> - You have 3 luck points. Whenever you make an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw, you can spend one luck point to roll an additional d20. You can choose to spend one of your luck points after you roll the die, but before the outcome is determined. You choose which of the d20s is used for the attack roll, ability check, or saving throw.
> - You can also spend one luck point when an attack roll is made against you. Roll a d20, and then choose whether the attack uses the attacker's roll or yours.

This is the exact wording of the [Divination Wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#SchoolofDivination)'s Portent feature (PHB, p. 116):

> When you finish a long rest, roll two d20 and record the numbers rolled. You can replace any attack roll, saving throw, or ability check made by you or a creature that you can see with one of these foretelling rolls. You must choose to do so before the roll, and you can replace a roll in this way only once per turn.
>
> Each foretelling roll can be used only once. When you finish a long rest, you lose any unused foretelling rolls.

### Similar Questions:

We know from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122748/portent-vs-lucky-feat-which-wins) that Portent overrides Lucky if the two are used against each other.

We know from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/577694965398024192) that the Portent die replaces "a d20 roll only, not any modifiers."

We know from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50734/how-does-the-diviners-portent-ability-interact-with-advantage-and-disadvantage) that Portent overrides advantage or disadvantage by replacing the end result of the roll. Furthermore that Lucky (the halfling trait, not the feat I'm talking about) deals with the **die roll** whereas Portent deals with the **check as a whole**.

### The Question

**Can you use Lucky to force a new roll and then use Portent to replace said roll before it happens?**

This may come down to whether or not the Lucky roll counts as an "attack roll" itself or whether the "attack roll" was the original roll and the Lucky roll is some other type of roll.

Alternately, it may be that Lucky replaces a *specific die roll*, whereas Portent replaces the *entire check as a whole* and therefore since the check has begun, you can no longer use Portent.

Whatever the case, I'd like to know how this interaction works.

Comment: Where the question says “Before the DM makes that roll”, could you clarify what roll that is referring to? I've read and re-read the Scenario section and the definition of Lucky and I can't find the roll this phrase is referring to, and it seems to be the crux of the question.

Comment: I'm still not clear after the edit. I can't find a die that is a) about to be rolled, b) could be called a Lucky die roll, c) is the DM's to roll.  Is that line asking if Portent can replace the monster's attack die that has already been rolled?

Comment: No. The TL;DR of it is that I'm asking:
1. Roll an attack
2. Use lucky to roll a second die for said attack
3. Intercede before the second die roll happens and use Portent to replace that one. The die being rerolled is the one that Lucky calls for.

Comment: Ah, so the one the player is rolling? There's a bit of “DM rolling” left in the previous edit. I'll do another edit to show you where I think it is. Check my edit for accuracy?

Comment: Yeah that's perfect! Thanks very much for helping me out, I apparently need some more sleep. I appreciate your dedication.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## From my reading, no.

As you mention in the question:

> This may come down to whether or not the Lucky roll counts as an "attack roll" itself or whether the "attack roll" was the original roll and the Lucky roll is some other type of roll.

Yes, this is the case. And Lucky is not an attack roll.

Lucky says:

> Whenever you make an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw, you can spend one luck point to roll an additional d20. [...] You choose which of the d20s is used for the attack roll, ability check, or saving throw.

You don't make a new attack roll - you just roll *an extra die* and then choose which die to use for the attack roll. The Lucky itself *is not an attack roll*, as much as attacking with advantage doesn't let you make *two attack rolls* or *two saving throws*, it is *one attack roll that has a "more complicated" math than just rolling*. Until you roll the additional d20 from Lucky, you are **in the middle of the attack roll** (just as you would be, for example, if you were rolling with advantage and rolled one die first, took a break and then rolled the other - you are in the middle of the same attack roll). Portent specifically asks "before the roll", so you can't use it.

For another example, a damage roll consists of all the damage dice summed, e.g. 2d6. Adding an extra 1d6 does not make an extra damage roll, just an extra damage die.